# ContentProviderOperation.withYieldAllowed() does it even work?

Tags: android, transactions, android-contentprovider, batch-processing

I need to execute a big batch of operations. To avoid blocking I need to begin and commit database transactions several times while executing this batch. I've read this [article](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/better-performance-with-contentprovideroperation/) about `ContentProviderOperation.withYieldAllowed()`. This would fit perfectly to my case.

What I don't understand is: how android is supposed to commit the transactions if the `ContentProvider.applyBatch()` method do not handle transactions ?. As the documentation (API 23) state to get the transactional behaviour your ContentProvider must override the method.

```
/**
 * Override this to handle requests to perform a batch of operations, or the
 * default implementation will iterate over the operations and call
 * {@link ContentProviderOperation#apply} on each of them.
 * If all calls to {@link ContentProviderOperation#apply} succeed
 * then a {@link ContentProviderResult} array with as many
 * elements as there were operations will be returned.  If any of the calls
 * fail, it is up to the implementation how many of the others take effect.
 * This method can be called from multiple threads, as described in
 * <a href="{@docRoot}guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#Threads">Processes
 * and Threads</a>.
 *
 * @param operations the operations to apply
 * @return the results of the applications
 * @throws OperationApplicationException thrown if any operation fails.
 * @see ContentProviderOperation#apply
 */
public @NonNull ContentProviderResult[] applyBatch(
```

So this mean I have to check if the operation allows yielding and commit the transaction myself inside my `applyBatch()` implementation ? This don't make much sense, what am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Please read carefully,

Whenever you use a ContentProviderOperation and have to insert, update or delete many records, the method withYieldAllowed() comes in handy.

The method withYieldAllowed() of the nested class ContentproviderOperation.Builder deals with this problem. Alas what this method does is not documented on the class itself.

Comment: So, does it cause ContentProvider to commit any transaction as it should or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below code

ArrayList() ops = new

ArrayList();

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.
         newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)

```
   .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, someAccountType)
```

.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, someAccountName)
   .build());